# Magento 2 system config Concatenate data to existing field with plugin beforeSave or aroundSave

Tags: magento2.2.2, system-config, around-plugin, before-plugin

I have a drop down field containing fruits where I would like to concatenate some data e.G:
[image]

Using a **Plugin** save the data like so:

`Bananas` **are high in potassium**  Where `are high in potassium` is the extra text added to it

Anyone any help thanks in advance!

Comment: so you want to display input text if select Bananas from drop down, am I right?

Comment: @kunj No! I would like to save Bananas + **other text** I interested in saving it not display. I know how to save using a plugin but I can't seem to find a way to add more data to a field before save.